# Counts return by sql query on sql developer is different then returned in the application

Tags: java, oracle, spring-mvc, timestamp

I am writing queries for a dashboard purpose. I am taking count from a table A based on the created_date column. My query is below

```
select 'New requests today' as Details,count(id) CNT 
from A  
where trunc(created_date)=trunc(systimestamp at  TIME ZONE 'US/Central')
```

When executed on sql developer I get count as 2 which is correct but as soon as the application runs the query the count is 3.

Below are the created_date of the 3 rows (all in CST)

```
11-OCT-19 10.27.14.634000000 AM 
11-OCT-19 10.04.11.247000000 AM
10-OCT-19 08.00.29.443000000 PM
```

So technically the count is 2 but I am assuming that somehow from application it's reading the third row `created_date` as `11-OCT-19 01.00.29.443000000 AM GMT`

Does anybody have an idea why it's happening like that and what could be the resolution?

Comment: Please post your table DDL, Specifically how is the column created_date defined?